# Angular 4 - How to properly use .find()?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've read most of questions similar to this, but still, I don't understand how to make `.find()` work in my app.

I have a service with API:

```
export class VehicleService {
  private defUrl = 'API';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getVehicleByVehicleId(vehicleid?: any) {
    const url = (!vehicleid) ? this.defUrl : 'API1&vehicle_id=' + vehicleid;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }


    searchVehicleId(description?: string) {
    const url = (!description) ? this.defUrl : 'API2&description=' + description;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(res => res.json().vehicles);
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
export class VehicleComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {

    this.searchQuery = new FormGroup({
      vehicleDescription: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
  }


  constructor(private vehicleService: VehicleService) { }

  public fleet: Fleet[];
  public description: Description[];
  public searchQuery: FormGroup;
  public searchVehicleId: any;


  public searchByVehicleId(searchQuery) {
    this.vehicleService
      .searchVehicleId(searchQuery.value.vehicleDescription)
      .subscribe(searchQuery => {
        this.description = searchQuery;
        this.searchVehicleId = this.description.find() // <= HOW TO IMPLEMENT THIS?
    this.vehicleService
      .getVehicleByVehicleId(this.searchVehicleId)
      .subscribe(searchQuery => {
        this.vehicle = searchQuery;
      })
      });
  }
interface Vehicle {
  status: number;
  dallases: Vehicle[];
}

interface VehicleDetails {
  vehicle_id: number;
  dallassettings: string;
  dallasupdated: string;
  dallas_list: DallasList[];
}

interface DallasList {
  number: number;
  auth: number;
}

//////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////

interface Description {
  vehicles: DescriptionDetails[];
}

interface DescriptionDetails {
  id: number;
  custom_description: string;
  description: string;
}
```

**API2**

```
{
    "vehicles": [{
        "description": "SKODA ROOMSTER",
        "id": 123456,
        "custom_description": ""
    }, {
        "description": "SKODA ROOMSTER",
        "id": 123456789,
        "custom_description": ""
    }]
}
```

So, what I do here is: pass `description` inside `FormGroup` - `vehicleDescription` field to `searchByVehicleId` method. Here I want to find `id` of passed `vehicleDescription` velue (it's `"description"` field in API2). When we find the `id`, we use it to further in `this.vehicleService.getVehicleByVehicleId`...

Main problem is - I have no idea, how to properly implement `.find()`.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35398031/4826457

Comment: Solved: `this.searchVehicleId = this.description.find(x => x.id === x.id).id.toString();`. Thanks for help, if I found this question earlier, there would be no question from my side.

Answer (score 2):

The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=example):

```
this.searchVehicleId = this.description.find(x => x.id === someId);
```